# Talend, If Statement with subconditions

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements, talend

I'm working on a Talend job where i need to insert informations in a column depending of informations to another column. For example, the target here is to insert "O" into "Saisie_manuelle_O_pour_Oui_sinon_rien" if "Code_direction" equals "D45" and "Fonction_libelle" not equals CHEF DE SERVICE or "Fonction_Libelle" not equals CHEF DE SERVICE ADJOINT.

For the moment i tried this :

```
if ("D45".equals(input_row.Code_direction) && (!("CHEF DE SERVICE".equals(input_row.Fonction_libelle) && !"CHEF DE SERVICE ADJOINT".equals(input_row.Fonction_libelle))) {
    output_row.Saisie_manuelle_O_pour_Oui_sinon_rien = "O";}
```

It work but not 100%. It put "O" everywhere where "Code_direction" = "D45" even if Fonction_libelle not equal CHEF DE SERVICE OR CHEF DE SERVICE ADJOINT...

I think i did something wrong but i'm not able to see what...

Any help will be very appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, for the moment i will do something else... I can do what i want by doing an other if statement after it, for example :

```
if ("D45".equals(input_row.Code_direction)) {
    output_row.Saisie_manuelle_O_pour_Oui_sinon_rien = "O";
}

if ("CHEF DE SERVICE".equals(input_row.Fonction_libelle) || "CHEF DE SERVICE ADJOINT".equals(input_row.Fonction_libelle)) {
    output_row.Saisie_manuelle_O_pour_Oui_sinon_rien = "";
}
```

This is not very clean but it's working ! I'll continue like this for the moment.